# Pandas, why does division done to other rows lead to additional trailing zeroes on final row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table that shows participation in Hong Kong demonstrations by gender for different dates in 2019 (obtained from [this](https://sites.google.com/view/antielabsurvey-eng/data-updated-until-oct-2019) source). The three first rows originally showed the percentage for males, females and unknown/unanswered. The final row shows the sample size. All data was initially of type string (the percentages included the % sign).

My DataFrame is titled gender_table

To be able to do some analysis, I first removed the percentage sign and changed the data to float type.

```
gender_table = gender_table.astype("float64")
```

This gives me the following:

[image: Image of part of table after converting to floats]

To change the percentage values into ratios, I thought I'd just divide all the data (except the final row with sample size) by 100.

```
gender_table[:-1] = gender_table[:-1]/100
```

gender_table now looks like this:

[image: Image of part of table after diving top rows by 100]

My question is this: Why has this operation added additional trailing zeroes to the sample size row?

*Pastebin with data (after removal of % signs) available [here](https://pastebin.com/f8j6w4pi) (can be saved as .csv and read into a Pandas df ("index_col=0")).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows of a column are formatted uniformly. The [default format for a float variable](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6258397047b9debc11bd77b3dd0cd60aa49762fd/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1192) `x` is `f'{x:.6g}'` (for details about format specifiers see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)).
So when you divide the first rows that had 1 decimal place by 100 they get 3 decimal places and as all rows in a column share the same format `285.0` becomes `285.000`.
This of course only changes the string representation of the values in the last row, the float values itself remain unchanged.